# Can i save one property of c# objcet into two fields of document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

For example I have class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Bob";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 33;
}
```

Can I save **Name** prop into two fields like

```
 {
    "Name": "Bob",
    "_sortingName": "bob",
    "Age": 33
}
```

My idea save sorting fields in lower case set index on it and sort by them. I want to avoid following:

```
 "$addFields" : 
             { 
                 "_tempSortName" : 
                 { 
                     "$toLower" : "$Name" 
                 } 
              }
```

Add some attribute to sorting field and save them in proper way.

Comment: [case insensitive index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) could be an alternative approach, depending on what you are filtering on

Comment: documentDb do not support it. "Field 'strength' is currently not supported"